# Resilience 4J with Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-sns, fault-tolerance, resilience4j

Is it a good idea to built fault tolerance over an Amazon SNS call. As Amazon services are built to be resilient should we add one more layer of fault tolerance or trust amazon to handle that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fallacies are of distributed computing:

- The network is reliable
- Latency is zero
- Bandwidth is infinite
- The network is secure
- Topology doesn't change
- There is one administrator
- Transport cost is zero
- The network is homogeneous

There are many network issues which can occur. Your application should also be resilient if network latency is high or even down on your side. It doesn't really matter which remote service you are calling.